# read from plist and load into image name/label text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist

I have no idea where this code is wrong. Please help, it is supposed to read a value from a dictionary and I use the value to call an image. I've tried to read the value as label.text but I got no result.

The only one I can call is from the nslog.

```
for (id key1 in dictionary)
{
    NSMutableString *textnamed = [dictionary objectForKey:key1];
    NSMutableString *imageDisplay =[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[dictionary objectForKey:key1]];

    eyeImageSaved.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageDisplay];

    labelSaved.text = textnamed;

    NSLog(@"%@",textnamed);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. There is nothing wrong with my code above, the mistake I made is that the object that is supposed to hold my variable and store in `plist` as the name of the image became null. So I added the object to `appdelegate.h`  as seen below:

### AppDelegate

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>  
{
    NSString *imageNameHolder;
}  
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *StorageDecider;
```

### View Controller

```
- (IBAction)lips2:(id)sender {  
    imageNameHolder = @"lips_blue";
} 

-(void)writeNewPlist  
{  
    AppDelegate* ref = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [dictionary setObject:imageNameHolder forKey:@"image1"];  
        [dictionary writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. First of all, you should consider using NSString instead of NSMutableString because it should be faster. Second, why are you putting the dictionary object in a string then calling the dictionary object again in the next line? That first line is unnecessary. It's entirely possible that the dictionary entry is not a string, and that is why you are having issues. You should write it like this `NSString *textnamed = (NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:key1]`. Also, `imageNamed` can only be used for files in the file bundle. Are you sure those pictures are stored there? There are a few other issues you could be having. What exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: what do you mean used for files in the file bundle? would you like to explain more?

Comment: You can place files in the file browser on the left hand side of XCode, and access those using `imageNamed:`, but if you were to download a file through your app, or access a file from a webpage, you don't access it using `imageNamed:`.

Answer (score 0):

`nameDataFormArray_` & `imageDataFormArray_` are `NSMutableArray`. Both have string and find image as per string (name of image).

```
- (void)readInfoFromThePlist
{    
    NSString* PListPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dataList" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray* tempDataList=[[NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithContentsOfFile:PListPath];
    for(NSDictionary *dataDict in tempDataList)
    {
        [nameDataFormArray_ addObject:[dataDict objectForKey:@"name"]];
        [imageDataFormArray_ addObject:[dataDict objectForKey:@"imagepath"]];
    }  

    [tempDataList release];
}
```